# Unable to create a box over a field in cics

Tags: dictionary, cics

This is my code for the map i've created with one field in it. I am trying to add a box or a line around this field, but it's not showing any lines. It is simply displaying the text i've entered in the initial:

```
WC00092 DFHMSD TYPE=&SYSPARM,MODE=INOUT,TERM=ALL,LANG=COBOL,   X
           TIOAPFX=YES,STORAGE=AUTO,CTRL=FREEKB,                          X
           DSATTS=(COLOR,HILIGHT,OUTLINE),                                X 
           MAPATTS=(COLOR,HILIGHT,OUTLINE)                          
WC00092 DFHMDI SIZE=(24,80),LINE=1,COLUMN=1                             
    DFHMDF POS=(5,13),LENGTH=28,                                   X
           INITIAL='PRAMOD''S EXAMINATION SYSTEM',                        X
           ATTRB=PROT,OUTLINE=BOX                                   
    DFHMSD TYPE=FINAL                                               
    END
```

Can anyone tell how to add a lines around these fields or an box around it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OUTLINE=BOX` may not be supported. From [DFHMSD](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/txformp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cics.te.doc%2Ferziai00162.htm) documentation:

> Some BMS attributes (for example COLOR or OUTLINE) use the screen manipulation facilities (extended curses) that are provided by the underlying operating system on which the IBM CICS Client is running. If the extended curses facility package does not support a particular attribute, it will be ignored. If a particular BMS attribute appears not to work, ensure first that it is supported by the extended curses facilities that are on the operating system on which the client is running.

My guess is that the OUTLINE attributes are not supported in your environment.